# Asset management in C++ for games

Tags: c++

I've been making a simple "game engine" for fun and I had a lot of trouble designing a decent asset management system. Currently I got it working but it uses a lot of downcasting which is usually bad practise.
The whole code wouldn't really fit here so I'm putting here the relevant parts and linking the whole thing on GitHub (https://github.com/ekardnam/Newtonic)

The design idea is this:

- I have an `AssetManager` class that is a singleton to which you can register specific instances of `IAssetCache` for caching assets and to which you register assets themselves (you assign an id and tell the manager how to load them, more on this later)
- I have an `AssetLoader` singleton to which you register different providers for different type of assets (which derive from `IAssetProvider`)

Here I'll post interfaces of such code

```
namespace Newtonic
{
  class IAssetCache
  {
  public:
    virtual AssetType GetCachedType() = 0;
    virtual void CollectGarbage() = 0;
  };

  template<typename T>
  class AssetCache : public IAssetCache
  {
  public:
    AssetType GetCachedType() override
    {
      return T::GetAssetType();
    }

    void CacheAsset(const std::string & id, std::shared_ptr<T> asset)
    {
      m_cache[id] = asset;
    }

    bool IsAssetCached(const std::string & id)
    {
      return (m_cache.find(id) != m_cache.end() && m_cache[id]);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> GetAsset(const std::string & id)
    {
      return m_cache[id];
    }

    void CollectGarbage() override
    {
      for (auto & kv : m_cache)
      {
        if (kv.second.use_count() == 1)
        {
          // in this case the only reference left is the cache reference
          // we can free the asset from the cache
          NW_WRAP_DEBUG(Core::GetCoreLogger().Debug(FormatString("Collecting asset %s of type %i", kv.first.c_str(), T::GetAssetType())));
          kv.second.reset();
        }
      }
    }

  private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<T>> m_cache;
  };
}
```

I feel that `IAssetCache` is a consequence of bad code design but I need it to store different instances of caches into a map in `AssetManager`.

Here asset manager

```
namespace Newtonic
{
  class AssetManager
  {
  public:
    static void RegisterCache(std::unique_ptr<IAssetCache> cache);
    static void RegisterAsset(const std::string & id, std::unique_ptr<AssetLoadingInformation> information);

    template<typename T>
    static std::shared_ptr<T> GetAsset(const std::string & id)
    {
      AssetType type = T::GetAssetType();
      if (s_caches.find(type) != s_caches.end())
      {
        ASSERT_TRUE(s_caches[type]->GetCachedType() == type);
        AssetCache<T> *cache = dynamic_cast<AssetCache<T>*>(s_caches[type].get());
        ASSERT_TRUE(cache != nullptr);
        if (cache->IsAssetCached(id))
        {
          return cache->GetAsset(id);
        }
        ASSERT_TRUE(s_loadingInformation.find(id) != s_loadingInformation.end());
        ASSERT_TRUE(s_loadingInformation[id]->type == type);
        std::shared_ptr<T> asset = AssetLoader::LoadAsset<T>(s_loadingInformation[id].get());
        cache->CacheAsset(id, asset);
        return asset;
      }
      NW_WRAP_DEBUG(Core::GetCoreLogger().Debug(FormatString("Cache for type %d not registered", type)));
      ASSERT_TRUE(s_loadingInformation.find(id) != s_loadingInformation.end());
      return AssetLoader::LoadAsset<T>(s_loadingInformation[id].get());
    }

    static void CollectGarbage();
  private:
    static std::unordered_map<AssetType, std::unique_ptr<IAssetCache>> s_caches;
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<AssetLoadingInformation>> s_loadingInformation;
  };
}
```

Here `AssetLoadingInformation` is a class that stores information on how to load an asset, this is what I meant by "registering assets" before (whether you want to load from a file system path or maybe in other ways, I guess it might be useful to have such feature in case I wanted to add more ways in the future). `AssetLoadingInformation` uses again polymorphism with downcasting but again I don't have any better ideas.

I think that posting also `AssetLoader` and `IAssetProvider` here would make the post untidy. The problem is actually the same that you have with the asset cache and manager, but I would be glad if you took a look at those files from the github repository.
The relevant files in the repo are the ones starting with asset in `newtonic/include` for headers and `newtonic/src` for implementation.

My main concerns are about downcasting and anyway the code feels a bit messy to me.

Comment: How many different asset types do you have? Is this supposed to be thread-safe in any way? BTW: Globals (and singletons are no different!) are usually considered a bad idea. Makes code hard to test. Prefer using dependency injection instead.

Answer (score 3):

Design:

It would be possible to use a single `AssetCache` for different types of asset by storing assets as `std::shared_ptr<void>` and casting back to the appropriate type using `std::static_pointer_cast`. They could be stored like:

```
        struct TypeID
        {
            std::type_index TypeIndex;
            std::string ID;
        };

        std::unordered_map<TypeID, std::shared_ptr<void>> m_assets; // (with appropriate hash and equality for TypeID)
```

The extra `std::type_index` per asset is probably not a concern if we're using `std::string` for asset IDs.

---

Code:

```
void CacheAsset(const std::string & id, std::shared_ptr<T> asset)
{
  m_cache[id] = asset;
}
```

We can move the asset into place: `m_cache[id] = std::move(asset);`. I'd question whether it's a good idea to allow an existing asset to be overwritten without explicitly removing the old asset from the cache first.

In addition to what *camp0* said about `bool IsAssetCached(const std::string & id)`, it should then be made `const`.

```
std::shared_ptr<T> GetAsset(const std::string & id)
{
  return m_cache[id];
}
```

This can also be `const` if we use `find` instead of `operator[]`.

```
void CollectGarbage() override
{
  for (auto & kv : m_cache)
  {
    if (kv.second.use_count() == 1)
    {
      // in this case the only reference left is the cache reference
      // we can free the asset from the cache
      NW_WRAP_DEBUG(Core::GetCoreLogger().Debug(FormatString("Collecting asset %s of type %i", kv.first.c_str(), T::GetAssetType())));
      kv.second.reset();
    }
  }
}
```

We could perhaps remove the empty map entries too.

```
template<typename T>
static std::shared_ptr<T> GetAsset(const std::string & id)
{
    ...

    ASSERT_TRUE(s_caches[type]->GetCachedType() == type);
    AssetCache<T> *cache = dynamic_cast<AssetCache<T>*>(s_caches[type].get());
```

Since we've just checked that the type is the same, we don't need `dynamic_cast`, and can use `static_cast` instead.

```
    if (cache->IsAssetCached(id))
    {
      return cache->GetAsset(id);
    }
```

We're doing two lookups here: once in `IsAssetCached`, and once in `GetAsset`. We could instead return an empty `std::shared_ptr<T>` from `GetAsset` if the asset is missing.

```
  class AssetManager
  {
  public:
    static ...
    static ...
```

Perhaps we could have an `AssetManager` instance somewhere, instead of one global one.

Comment: First about string ids, I probably may want to turn them into integer ids, I used strings because in the previous implementation I had I used strings and I wanted to avoid changing to much of other working code to test this. I should probably map string ids to integer ids and use integer ids instead

Comment: Second, probably about existsting asset being overwritten there should be an assertion as anyway id should be unique and one asset shouldn't be overwritten by a different asset

Comment: I thought I couldn't use static_cast when downcasting but if I actually can in there it would be great

Comment: Yeah doing on lookup there would be better

Comment: I know singletons are bad design, but in the end I feel like using a singleton here isn't that much of an issue, there actually shouldn't be more than one instanced and if using a non global instance I would have to pass a reference to it around to such many other stuff that I'm unsure it would actually be better

Comment: Could you take a look at this commit if you have time https://github.com/ekardnam/Newtonic/commit/b7f92675666c6e43e4119573b21ab39fb25df799 I still didn't make AssetManager non-global tho'

Comment: Note that in `CollectGarbage()` when calling `m_cache.erase(iter)`, the erased iterator is invalidated and can't be used to get the next item in the container. `erase` returns the next valid iterator itself. For an example see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase

Comment: Yep indeed. That was caused because I was writing in a hurry and didn't double check

Answer (score 1):

I just notice that you are making two lookups that impact the performance of your operation *IsAssetCached*

```
bool IsAssetCached(const std::string & id)
{
  return (m_cache.find(id) != m_cache.end() && m_cache[id]);
}
```

You don't need to do the m_cache[id]

```
bool IsAssetCached(const std::string & id)
{
  return (m_cache.find(id) != m_cache.end());
}
```

Comment: This breaks the code.  If an id is in the cache but the value associated with it is a nullptr, your version will return `true` when it should return `false`.

Comment: I don't think is a good design having containers that have shared_ptrs that could be nullptr. On a container, you have objects, but you don't have entries that could be nullptr, or may be im missing something.

Comment: Good design or not, the original code allows for the possibility that a cached value can be null, and your proposed rewrite does not, which changes the behavior.

Comment: An empty shared_ptr (ie points to nullptr) is created when an asset is freed by CollectGarbage. As user673679 stated in his answer I should probably just remove those from the map

Comment: An actually if for any reason the user code calls reset on an asset shared_ptr you would have nullptr in there no?